# Reason for Integer and Character primitive-wrapper classes naming

Tags: java, naming

Why do `Integer` and `Character` deviate from the primitive names `int` and `char`?

All other types match:

- `Byte`
- `Short`
- `Long`
- `Double`
- `Float`
- `Boolean`

Rediculous question, but couldn't find an answer for it.

Comment: Most likely because the Java class naming conventions (last revised in 1999) state "Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations" However it also states "(unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML)." which is this case would be a potentially valid reason for using `Char` or `Int`. [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Just a guess, but char and int were probably chosen to match the primitive C types, and Integer and Character were used for the classes because the naming conventions of Java don't promote the use of abbreviations in class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple guess.
All wrapper classes are not abbreviated name but complete names.
Using complete name makes sense for classes as these are designed to represent a concept and abbreviating them is not advised to represent clearly a concept.

On the other hand, I suppose that having a shorthand as `int` or `char` may appear as more acceptable for primitive types.
They also could choose  `bool` rather than `boolean`.

Comment: Oke, that seems logical. Same as what JB Nizet said.